# Upcasting Downcasting

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a parent class `class A` and a child class `class C extends A`.

```
A a=new A();
C c=(C)a;
```

This gives me error. Why?

Also if my code is

```
A a=new A();
C c=new C();
c=(C)a;
```

This works fine.

Now what all methods can my `c` variable access..the ones in C or the ones in class B?

Comment: not understand ur question :(

Comment: Your 'this works fine' example doesn't even compile

Comment: When you say "gives me error" it is better to paste the error you get, whether it is a compile error or runtime error. If it is an exception then print the stack trace and mention the line in code that gets the exception because the pasted code does not have line numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's giving you an error because `a` *isn't* an instance of `C` - so you're not allowed to downcast it. Imagine if this *were* allowed - you could do:

```
Object o = new Object();
FileInputStream fis = (FileInputStream) o;
```

What would you expect to happen when you tried to read from the stream? What file would you expect it to be reading from?

Now for the second part:

```
A a=new A();
C c=new C();
C c=(C)a;
```

That will *not* work fine - for a start it won't even compile as you're declaring the same variable (`c`) twice; if you fix that mistake you'll *still* get an exception when you try to cast an instance of `A` to `C`.

This code, however, is genuinely valid:

```
A a = new C(); // Actually creates an instance of C
C c = (C) a; // Checks that a refers to an instance of C - it does, so it's fine
```

Comment: Man Jon Skeet can even compile code that's not there! :)  (edit: this  was before the OP's edit)

Comment: @Jon Skeet  i am sorry, i meant the child class is C.

Comment: @Karan: Yes, that's what I've been assuming. The whole answer assumes that C is a subclass of A.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpFij6RD7CA which demonstrates the same. Below is a full textual information for the same.

“Upcasting” means moving subclass object to the parent class object. “DownCasting” is opposite to “Upcasting” moving the parent object to the child object.

[image]

“Upcasting” is perfectly valid but “Downcasting” is not allowed in .NET. For instance below is a simple “Customer” parent class which is further inherited by a child class “GoldCustomer”.

```
class Customer
{

}

class GoldCustomer : Customer
{

}
```

Below is an “upcasting” code where the child parent class gold customer is pushed to the customer class.

```
Customer obj = new GoldCustomer();
```

Below is a sample of “downcasting” code where parent class object is tried to move to a child class object, this is not allowed in .NET.

```
GoldCustomer obj = new Customer(); // not allowed illegal
```

Answer (score 1):

In java there is concept that without upcasting u can't perform downcasting

A a=new A();
C c=(C)a;

in this case u try to perform downcast with out upcasting

Answer (score 0):

A is not a subclass of C hence you cannot cast it down.

Answer (score 0):

While casting the objects what we need to keep in mind is to apply **is a** relationship to the instances.
Like in your example **C is A** but **A is not C**.

So in your case,
A a=new A();
C c=(C)a; // classCasteException occures.

I think this might help you.