# Downcasting and upcasting in java(very simple manner)

Tags: java

I am new to java,can someone explain `Downcasting` and `upcasting` in java( in very simple manner) to understand well.please give some example.

Comment: Didn't even try _Googling_ this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489619/upcasting-downcasting

Comment: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~cannata/cs345/Class%20Notes/14%20Java%20Upcasting%20Downcasting.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"UpCasting": 
It means That when you have subclass you can Casting it to SuperClass , so this is legal casting.

"DownCasting" 
It measn That You want casting a superClass to SubClass. It is Dangerous And in Java is Ilegal, so you can,t do downCasting.

For Example:
`Creacher` is SuperClass. `Human` extend creacher. both `man` and `woman` extends Human Class. you can Cast man and woman class to Human and Creacher
  because both of them is superclass of man and woman class.but you never can cast Creacher Class to Human or Man or woman class because all of them are sub Class of 
creacher.

we also call Upcastin as "widing" and call dowcasting as "Narrowing"

This Link helps you.
[Upcasting Downcasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489619/upcasting-downcasting?rq=1)